# MySql trigger insert ater insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables- apartments and tenants. I need a trigger that creates dummy tenant every time I create a new apparment. For example:

```
TABLE APARTMENT:
ID | AP_NUMBER | APP_DESC 
------------------------
5  |   7        | new_app
```

and then I would like it to fill new dummy tenant for the TENANT table which looks like that:

```
ID | AP_ID | NAME | LAST_NAME | DATE_MOVED_IN 
-----------------------------------------------
```

in this example I created new apartment which has ID=5.
In TENANT table I want the foreign key (APP_ID )
to be filled with 5, NAME and LAST_NAME as "blank" and DATE_MOVED_IN with today's date.

Appreciate your help,
Maciej

Comment: This seems like a very dangerous thing to do in practice.  Is there a reason why you want to do this?

Comment: I create an application that will be used to maintain cost of water gas and electricity. For integrity Issue I want that appartment to have a tenant. My application will load the data and if there is a tenant with "blank" name on it then it will treat this house as empty. Otherwise it will recognize a tenant and take it's data. Either way I want some values that are linked to the newly created appartment.

Comment: With the same logic if a tenant moves out of an apartment and nobody moves in to replace him I will manually add a "dummy" tenant so that my application will know that there is nobody from that apartment to create bill for

Comment: . . To me, that seems misleading and could cause confusion in other parts of your application and reporting process.  It just seems like `tenant IS NULL` would be a pretty good indicator that the apartment has no tenant.